# CSSLint calls @bulletproof-font-face 'unknown'

Tags: css

CSSLint complains that these rules are unknown:

```
@bulletproof-font-face {
  font-family: "Computer Modern";
  src: url('cmunss-webfont.woff') format('woff');
}
@bulletproof-font-face {
  font-family: "Computer Modern";
  src: url('cmunsi-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-style: italic, oblique;
}
@bulletproof-font-face {
  font-family: Arial;
  src: url('arial-webfont.woff') format('woff');
}
@bulletproof-font-face {
  font-family: Verdana;
  src: url('verdana-webfont.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Yet, for example, this rule it deems okay:

```
@bulletproof-font-face {
  font-family: "Computer Modern";
  src: url('cmunsx-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

I don't see the difference.  Why would it do that?

Comment: That code looks like it's intended to be used by some sort of CSS pre-processor like less.js or sass (though I'm unsure of the actual syntax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of those rules are ok.

Try it yourself.  http://csslint.net/

The reason they are not ok is that @bulletproof-font-face is not valid css.  I've never heard of it before.

Here's a [list of all the `@rules` that exist in css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/At-rule).

Comment: explain for me, Lint notices 2/4 rules are unknown, not all.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is a bug in CSS lint.  When there are two consecutive @bulletproof-font-face rules, it doesn't find the second one.

Comment: By the way, I tend to trust the w3 css validator more.  It does find them all.   http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator

Comment: recursive, that is the same response I get from CSSLint.  Thank you all for your input; I'll stick with regular @font-face.

Comment: Forgot to mention that these errors were returned using the CSSLint plugin for [Brackets](http://brackets.io/).